# Plugin Eclipse Dependencies

Tags: eclipse, plugins, dependencies, buildpath

I have the following problem :
In the same workspace I have 3 projects, one is a plugin project, the other two contain classes that I should use in the plugin.
How can I set the dependencies?
The error is:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-11-05 15:53:12.721
!MESSAGE The activator amedeoantonio.Activator for bundle AmedeoAntonio is invalid
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: The activator amedeoantonio.Activator for bundle AmedeoAntonio is invalid...![enter image description here][1] 
Root exception:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: amedeoantonio.Activator"
```

Thank you!!

Comment: I think you should add them as a Library Project by goign to project-->properties and add then in bottom u can see...

Answer (score 2):

Plug-ins can only rely on other plug-ins or jars they contain themselves. The other two projects need to either be plug-ins as well, with dependencies stated between the first one and them, or their compiled jars need to be packaged into the plug-in your have and made part of its classpath in the MANIFEST.MF file.